# [C++]operators malfunction when I include parenthesis?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

when I perform `12*20/100`, I get `2` as the output

but when I perform `12*(20/100)`, I get `0` as the output

So does anyone know why the brackets affect the output?

Comment: Because of **integer arithmetic** i.e. `integer/integer = integer`. Brackets have got nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `(20/100)` as integer division evaluates to `0`. use `(20.0/100)` to get `0.2`. Without parentheses you have `240 / 100 = 2` (as integer)

Answer (score 0):

**In mathematics**, parentheses don't matter for your expression.

But **C++ computation** (especially integer arithmetic) **isn't mathematics**. You already understand that, as you accept `12*20/100` being `2` instead of `2.4`.

Setting parentheses defines what to compute first (as in mathematics), so `12*(20/100)` first computes `20/100`, giving `0`, and then `12*0`, giving `0`.

Comment: I disagree, not all calculation "in mathematics" happens in ℝ or whatever domain you had in mind. This kind of integer division goes all the way back to Euclid around 300BCE, it's certainly not just some unmathematical C++ quirk.